# Google Sheets: data validation stuck in infinite 'loading'

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

**Background**:

I've written a dynamic data validation script that takes a parameter from column C, looks it up in a range, and  produces a new data validation rule in column D.

**Problem**:

The script has been working flawlessly for a few weeks with 0 errors, and today it's suddenly started getting infinitely stuck at 'loading'. The error message reads: 'Exception: The starting column of the range is too small.' I've tried adjusting the range to be a hard-coded one instead, but the same things happens. Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve?

**Code snippet below:**

```js
function onEdit(){
  
  //establishing variables
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var frontSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Front Sheet");
  var datass = ss.getSheetByName("Data Validation");
  var activeCell = frontSheet.getActiveCell();
  var originRange = datass.getRange(1, 1, datass.getLastRow(), 11);
  
  //Only activating the function when changes are made in 3rd column of front sheet
  
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 3 && activeCell.getRow() > 3 && SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName() == "Front Sheet"){
      
    
    //Establish positions of the data ranges in valduation rule tab
    
    var origins = datass.getRange(1,1,1,11).getValues();
    var originIndex = origins[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue())+1;
    
    //Creating the validation rule based on the position of item selected in the top row of Lookup tab
  
    var validRange = datass.getRange(2,originIndex, originRange.getLastRow,1);
    var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validRange).build();
  
    //Apply the validation rule 1 column to the right
    
    frontSheet.getActiveCell().offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule)
  }
  
}
```

Comment: I think origins[0] is not an array it’s a single value so indexOf() is always returning a -1 so originIndex is always zero.

Comment: What line is the error occurring on? Also, just to note, `onEdit` has an event object parameter, making the function definition `onEdit(e)`. It would be better to use `e.range` than `frontSheet.getActiveCell()`. Reference: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not handling the case for when the active cell value (`activeCell.getValue()`) is not found in the `origins` array. If it's not found, `indexOf` method will return `-1` and `originIndex` will be 0, causing this line:

`var validRange = datass.getRange(2,originIndex, originRange.getLastRow,1);`

To throw the error `Exception: The starting column of the range is too small.`, because rows and columns start counting from 1. Also, it's better if you use `e.range` to get the edited range from the trigger event instead of `getActiveCell` to avoid a missmatch if the active range in the sheets changes while running the trigger function. Here's an example code:

```
function onEdit(e){

  //establishing variables
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var frontSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Front Sheet");
  var datass = ss.getSheetByName("Data Validation");
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var originRange = datass.getRange(1, 1, datass.getLastRow(), 11);

  //Only activating the function when changes are made in 3rd column of front sheet
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 3 && activeCell.getRow() > 3 && SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName() == "Front Sheet"){

    //Establish positions of the data ranges in valduation rule tab
    var origins = datass.getRange(1,1,1,11).getValues();
    var originIndex = origins[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue());
    if(origins[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) !== -1 ) {
      originIndex += 1;

      //Creating the validation rule based on the position of item selected in the top row of Lookup tab
      var validRange = datass.getRange(2,originIndex, originRange.getLastRow,1);
      var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validRange).build();

      //Apply the validation rule 1 column to the right
      frontSheet.getActiveCell().offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule)
    }
    else {
      console.log('Edited range not found in origins');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're right, that's the problem. After pivoting to e.range it's started producing results again. Thank you!